# Is there a faster way to merge two dicts of sets in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

dict_current and dict_all are two dicts with sets as their values. I want to merge anything in dict_current into dict_all. And the testing code is below:

```
value_1 = {('x', 1),('y', 2), ('z',3)}
value_2 = {('x', 8),('y', 2), ('z',3)}
value_3 = {('x', 11)}

dict_current = {'a': value_1}
dict_all = {'a': value_2, 'b': value_3}

for k, v in dict_current.items():
    if k in dict_all:
        dict_all[k].update(v)
    else:
        dict_all[k] = v

print(dict_all)
```

If the dict_current is big, the for loop takes quite some time for each merging. Is there a faster way to achieve this merging?

Comment: @0x5453 that absolutely doesn't do what the OP wants.

Comment: @0x5453 That's for merging dictionaries with different keys. This question needs elements with the same keys to be combined.

Comment: Anyway, no I don't think there is any way to do this more efficiently

Comment: The key is that my dict has set as value, so even for the same key, the merging doesn't simply replace the value with the new value. It needs update the set.

Comment: The bottleneck is all the set merging. The looping method isn't going to improve that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So probably there is no way to get rid of the loop to decide how to merge?

Comment: When merging two `dict`s, Python only supports right-biased *replacement* of values, not merging them.

Comment: Not a major improvement, but think the if-condition is unnecessary. Just update in any case.

Comment: @marlon the loop is trivial

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that is not faster.

We can "flatten" the original `dict` of `set` into a monolithic `set` of tuples pairing each original key with each of that key's set members (which are themselves lower level tuples).  This preserves the restriction that each original key is associated with one or more tuples (these lower level tuples can be repeated across different keys, but cannot be repeated within a particular key).

```
def flatter(dict_data):
    # Return set with each dict key paired with each member of key's value.
    return set((k, member) for k, v in dict_data.items() for member in v)

flatter({'a': value_2, 'b': value_3})
# {('a', ('x', 1)),
#  ('a', ('x', 8)),
#  ('a', ('y', 2)),
#  ('a', ('z', 3)),
#  ('b', ('x', 11))}
```

Now to update `dict_all` from `dict_current` we apply `flatter` to each, use `set.update`, and then turn it into a dataframe and use `groupby.aggregate` to turn it back into a `dict` of `set`.

```
import pandas as pd

def updater2(dict_all, dict_current):
    # Alternative single monolithic update.

    # Explode key-set pairs into set of key-member pairs.
    flatter_all = flatter(dict_all)

    # Update from current key-member pairs.
    flatter_all.update(flatter(dict_current))

    # Assemble set for each key from key-member pairs.
    return pd.DataFrame.from_records(list(flatter_all), columns=["k", "v"]) \
                .groupby("k").aggregate(set)["v"].to_dict()
```

To compare speed, we might try about 10,000 dictionary entries.  The original loop approach takes about 4ms.  The alternative monolithic single update approach takes about 260ms, about 65 times longer.  Ouch!

```
def updater1(dict_all, dict_current):
    # Original loop over current and update if already in all.
    for k, v in dict_current.items():
        if k in dict_all:
            dict_all[k].update(v)
        else:
            dict_all[k] = v

# 10,000 entries in current, plus a handful more in all.
size = 10000
data_current = {n: value_1 for n in range(size)}
data_all = {n: value_2 if n < size else value_3 for n in range(size+5)}

# Time original.
%timeit updater1(data_all, data_current)
# 3.69 ms ± 92.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


# Set up data again since updater1 modifies data_all.
data_current = {n: value_1 for n in range(size)}
data_all = {n: value_2 if n < size else value_3 for n in range(size+5)}

# Time alternative single monolithic update.
%timeit updater2(data_all, data_current)
# 257 ms ± 20.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Even if we pre-flatten the dictionaries and just keep our data in the flatter form it does not beat the speed of the original.  This comes in at about 9ms, more than twice as long as the time required for the original algorithm on this test data.

```
def updater3(flatter_all, flatter_current):
    # Update set flatter_all from set flatter_current.
    flatter_all.update(flatter_current)

# 10,000 entries in current, plus a handful more in all.
flatter_current = flatter({n: value_1 for n in range(size)})
flatter_all = flatter({n: value_2 if n < size else value_3
                       for n in range(size+5)}
                      )

# Time single monolithic update of flattened set.
%timeit updater3(flatter_current, flatter_all)
# 8.68 ms ± 738 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```